# dropdown menu is hiding behind toolbar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, ionic4

i am using ionic4/angular. on-clicking on the ion-avatar a dropdown menu should display but the dropdown menu is hiding in the toolbar. i tried giving z-index but it is not working. Thanks.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1dejvq)

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="tertiary" >

    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <button class="btn btn-light">My Courses</button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button class="iconbell">
        <ion-icon name="notifications-outline" size="large"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ion-avatar class="dropdown-toggle" style="margin-right:10px;height: 5vh;width: 5vh;" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <img [src]="user['profpic']"> <span class="caret"></span>
        </ion-avatar>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">About Us</a></li>    
        </ul>
      </div>

    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: I don't know much about angular but you can try placing your dropdown menu code outside the <ion-buttons slot="end"> tag or remove the <ion-buttons slot="end"> to check if it is working.

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 2):

```
Please add or update css 

.toolbar{
    contain: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: there is no toolbar class. can u edit the stackblitz

Comment: please check given URL

Comment: It is working in stackblitz but not working in actual project. anyway thankyou

Answer (score 2):

There are contain property inside shadow-root with static value [ without dynamic CSS variables ] and that we can override as rule of ionic shadow-element.

[example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGpvJxJhGz6G-ztusZSquHbOaN0SUfvw/view?usp=sharing)

You can go with popover option of ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working with a dropdown but instead I used the ionic popover component and just implemented something myself.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover